# Remove retried tests marked as skipped from testng report

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, testng

I'm using `RetryAnalyzer` to retry tests that got failed and `TestListenerAdapter` to remove retried tests from testng report because all retried tests are also counted in report. But my solution does not work and retried test (that are marked as skipped) are also counted in total amount

I used `RetryAnalizer` to retry tests:

```
package generics;

import org.testng.IRetryAnalyzer;
import org.testng.ITestResult;

public class RetryAnalyzer  implements IRetryAnalyzer {

    private int retryCount = 0;
    private int maxRetryCount = 1;

    @Override
    public boolean retry(ITestResult result) {
        if (retryCount < maxRetryCount) {
            retryCount++;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

use `IAnnotationTransformer` class:

```
package generics;

import org.testng.IAnnotationTransformer; 
import org.testng.annotations.ITestAnnotation; 
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor; 
import java.lang.reflect.Method; 

public class TestTranformer implements IAnnotationTransformer {

    @Override
    public void transform(ITestAnnotation iTestAnnotation, Class aClass, Constructor constructor, Method method) {
       iTestAnnotation.setRetryAnalyzer(RetryAnalyzer.class);
    }
}
```

`TestListenerAdapter` to remove retired test that are marked as skipped from testngreport:

```
package generics;

import java.util.Set;
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.ITestNGMethod;
import org.testng.ITestResult;

public class TestListenerAdapter extends org.testng.TestListenerAdapter {


    @Override
    public void onFinish(ITestContext context) {
        Set<ITestResult> failedTests = context.getSkippedTests().getAllResults();
        for (ITestResult temp : failedTests) {
            ITestNGMethod method = temp.getMethod();
            if (context.getFailedTests().getResults(method).size() > 1) {
                failedTests.remove(temp);
            } else {
                if (context.getPassedTests().getResults(method).size() > 0) {
                    failedTests.remove(temp);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {   }

    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {   }

    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {   }

    public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result) {   }

    public void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult result) {   }

    public void onStart(ITestContext context) {   }
}
```

Added both classes to testng.xml file:

```
<listeners>
        <listener class-name="generics.TestTranformer"/>
        <listener class-name="generics.TestListenerAdapter"/>
</listeners>
```

[image: test result snapshot]

I run my suite in Jenkins and in results are counted also retried test, but I want to remove them. What is the problem with my code?